# Missing semi-colon in JavaScript causing "'foo' is undefined" error in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I just spent about four hours tracking down this problem. I know what is causing it but don't know why and the "why" is bugging me.

I have the following .js file:

```
function funcA() {
}
function funcB() {
    do {
    } while (1 == 1) return 0
}
```

I also have the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new funcA();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in IE9 I get an error that "'funcA' is undefined." I can get rid of the run-time error by do **any one** of the following:

- Turning on Compatibility View in IE9
- Removing the DOCTYPE from the page
- Adding a semi-colon after the while and before the return in the JavaScript (i.e. while (1 = 1); return 0)

Can anyone help me understand what exactly is going on here?

Comment: `1 = 1` is a syntax error as well...

Comment: the whole statement `} while (1 = 1) return 0` is wrong.

Comment: The code I posted is a severely stripped down version of the actual code. Regardless of the points made above the rest of my post is accurate as to the circumstances that cause the error to appear and do go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not require you to explicitly put in semi-colons everywhere that there should be one - but it will internally put those in for you. This can often lead to hard to trace bugs and unexpected behavior.

Among other syntax errors in your code (as others have pointed out), the `;` after the `while` in a `do-while` *is* required and when you put in there, things work as you expect them to. When this isn't done, it's pretty much impossible for the casual developer to predict how different environments will behave without digging deep into the specs of the language and the JS engine *and* understanding it all - assuming there are no bugs in the implementation of the JS engine itself. [Little things such as whether you have braces ( `{` and `}` ) in the same line or not can make a difference](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/).

Comment: to expand on NGAC's great answer, this is why www.jslint.com was invented.  (not that I agree with all the decisions jslint makes - in fact, in its most recent incarnation it's useless due to incredible pickiness about where var appears!)

Comment: @DDaviesBrackett others feel the same way about jslint, and have made an alternative: http://jshint.com/

Comment: The worst part about trying to debug this issue was that the actual js file is a minified file that has over 40,000 characters on one line. I had to run it through the javascript beautifier (http://jsbeautifier.org) so I could read the thing. I also ran it through jslint and it reported many violations, mostly about missing curly braces and semi-colons, but the original file is part of a package we bought so I don't want to make too many changes to it. It just seemed strange that a missing semi-colon in one function would cause IE to complain that it couldn't find the other function.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - Regarding: "...it's really pretty much impossible to predict how different environments will behave." That might be true, but the spec *does* set forth very specific rules that browsers *should* be following.

Comment: @lwburk You're right; a little hyperbole there to drive home the point :) I've edited it a little to indicate that the behavior is probably deterministic but not necessarily obvious.

Comment: @Craig W - I'm guessing that insertion of a semi-colon where JS thought it was required caused some block of code to become unreachable. Unlike in Java or other languages you might be used to, you can easily add a return and make some code unreachable or have functions nested within other functions among other things that can cause code that looks just fine to you to be interpreted very differently by the machine.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), IE's behavior is *correct*. See sections:

- **7.9.1 Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion** (which describes the
  cases in which a semi-colon may be
  inserted, none of which apply)
- **12.6.1 The do-while Statement** (which shows that your code is not a valid production of the form `do Statement while ( Expression );`

Comment: Which IE behavior is correct, the behavior with compatibility mode on or off? And why does the DOCTYPE being present or not make a difference?