# Only one function executes

Tags: php, javascript

I have a `.js` file with these two functions:

```
function download510(form) { 
    if (form.pass.value=="tokheim") {              
        location="../pdf/quantium-510.pdf" 
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Password")
    }
};

function download410(form) { 
    if (form.pass.value=="tokheim") {              
        location="../pdf/quantium-410.pdf" 
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Password")
    }
};
```

And two `.php` files with:

## 1:

```
<form name="login">
    <input name="pass" type="password"> 
    <input type="button" value="Download" onClick="download510(this.form)">
</form>
```

## 2:

```
<form name="login">
    <input name="pass" type="password"> 
    <input type="button" value="Download" onClick="download410(this.form)">
</form>
```

Only the first function, `download510(form)`, works. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your error console say? What exactly isn't working as you expect it to?

Comment: Just to make sure - you are aware that this password check is trivial to circumvent by looking into the JavaScript source code? It does not provide any security except for the most unexperienced user.

Comment: You have to close the input tag: `<input name=""... />`

Comment: I hope, you know that everyone could read the password..

Comment: I'd change the alert of the second function to slightly different text just to make sure it's not always going to that second condition.  The rest of your code might help to diagnose this as well.

Comment: @AyeshK: Not in HTML5 :-)

Comment: please add `;` to the end of your lines. JS is not like python, and you should always add `;`. And in front of `function abc() { ... }` no `;` is needed.

Comment: the only ; he did add were not required, lol :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @RocketHazmat. Didn't really knew that.

Comment: You don't close `<input>` in HTML, no matter the version. You're thinking of XHTML.

Comment: @fmsf Semicolons aren't required...

Comment: Is the php file that isn't working importing the .js file correctly using <script>?

Comment: Your code works fine, Check here, http://jsfiddle.net/wjgUA/2/ . Check whether you included correct JS files or check you added the function definitions.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes im aware, its just something to keep an average user from it, its not top secret :)
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/login.js"></script> is added in both php files.
there is no error, nothing is happening when i click the "download" button in the second php file only the fist one is working

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
function download510(form) { 
   if (document.getElementById("pass").value=="tokheim") {              
      location="../pdf/quantium-510.pdf" ;
   } else {
      alert("Invalid Password");
   }
}
```

With this php file

```
<form name="login">
    <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password"> 
    <input type="button" value="Download" onClick="download510(this.form)">
</form>
```

And, this other function:

```
function download410(form) { 
    if (document.getElementById("pass").value=="tokheim") {              
        location="../pdf/quantium-410.pdf" ;
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Password");
    }
}
```

With this php file:

```
<form name="login">
    <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password"> 
    <input type="button" value="Download" onClick="download410(this.form)">
</form>
```

Dont use the 2 functions together; the same with the forms....if you try it to use together change the name of the value input, like:

```
<input name="pass1" id="pass1" type="password">
```

and

```
<input name="pass2" id="pass2" type="password">;
```

Do the same with the names on each of the JS functions.

Saludos.

Comment: And i think its a problem about how you are using these functions...and using the same name for the input boxes on both forms

Comment: still noting, maybe im better of adding the script in the head section of every php file :(

Comment: You have separate files for each form....or you are displaying both forms on the same page??

Answer (score -1):

You don't indicate what you mean by 'not working' but one possible avenue would be to use `onSubmit` instead of `onClick` for your forms. If you want to block submission in the case of the incorrect password you return false from the function. Otherwise the form will be submitted.

Of course, this is in addition to all the other issues inherent in this code.. visible passwords, links, missing semi-colons.. etc...

Comment: Why are missing semicolons a problem?

Comment: Some js interpreters will get upset and put these lines together. Some interpreters will add them for you - but possibly not as intended. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397275/missing-semi-colon-in-javascript-causing-foo-is-undefined-error-in-ie9

Comment: Yeah so what's wrong with that? Ever heard of minifying code? You think it bothers to keep semicolons in? There are like 2 cases where if you don't use semicolons or formatting properly, that it will actually matter. Otherwise, semicolons basically never make a difference.